# Stop/disable nginx auto upgrade?

Tags: nginx, debian-squeeze

Is it possible to disable the nginx self update? My server was offline last night, because the auto update was broken/incomplete/etc.

After the upgrade, the nginx directory contains files like *nginx.conf.dpkg-new*.

On Debian Squeeze (6.0.5) 64-Bit.

Comment: This would depend on what OS/Package Management you are using, and how you handle updates for your OS. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @DrewKhoury I edit the post. Debian Squeeze (6.0.5) 64-Bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you want to be running your updates in a development environment before running them on production.

Also, compiling your own software will give you greater control over which versions are installed, and when.

Finally, if you like, you can prevent certain packages from being upgraded.

http://www.debianadmin.com/how-to-prevent-a-package-from-being-updated-in-debian.html

```
echo "package hold" | dpkg --set-selections
```

or

```
aptitude hold package_name
```

depending on which package manager you're using.